# Basic peak editing with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Usually I have really noisy datasets, so peak detection is quite hard to do just with coding. However the human brain immediately sees what is just random noise.
I decided to make a basic peak editing functionality with matplotlib. I added a toggle button to the navigation toolbar to switch on and off the recording. This is necessary because this way we can safely zoom.
Note that this is a private class, which is not called explicitly by the user, that's why I don't have too detalied docstrings there (Mostly input validation is done elsewhere). Basically the x, y are the dataset, x_extremal and y_extremal are the detected peaks in the dataset.

```py
import warnings

# for matplotlib
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning) 

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
from matplotlib.backend_tools import ToolToggleBase

def get_closest(x_value, x_array, y_array):
    """Finds the closest point in a graph to a given x_value, where distance is 
       measured with respect to x.
     """
    idx = (np.abs(x_array - x_value)).argmin()
    value = x_array[idx]
    return value, y_array[idx], idx

class SelectButton(ToolToggleBase):
    """
    Toggle button on matplotlib toolbar.
    """
    description = 'Enable click records'
    default_toggled = True
    default_keymap = 't'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class EditPeak:
    """
    This class helps to record and delete peaks from a dataset.
    Right clicks will delete the closest (distance is measured
    with regards to x) extremal point found on the graph, left
    clicks will add a new point. Edits can be saved by just
    closing the matplotlib window.
    """
    def __init__(self, x, y, x_extremal=None, y_extremal=None):

        # This is here because we don't want other figures
        # to change.
        matplotlib.rcParams["toolbar"] = "toolmanager"

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.cid = None
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        plt.plot(self.x, self.y, 'r')
        self.x_extremal = x_extremal
        self.y_extremal = y_extremal
        if not len(self.x_extremal) == len(self.y_extremal):
            raise ValueError('Data shapes are different')
        self.press()
        self.lins, = plt.plot(
            self.x_extremal, self.y_extremal, 'ko', markersize=6, zorder=99
            )
        plt.grid(alpha=0.7)
        # adding the button to navigation toolbar
        tm = self.figure.canvas.manager.toolmanager
        tm.add_tool('Toggle recording', SelectButton)
        self.figure.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool(
            tm.get_tool('Toggle recording'), "toolgroup"
            )
        self.my_select_button = tm.get_tool('Toggle recording')
        plt.show()

    def on_clicked(self, event):
            """ Function to record and discard points on plot."""
            ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
            if self.my_select_button.toggled:
                if event.button is MouseButton.RIGHT:
                    ix, iy, idx = get_closest(
                        ix, self.x_extremal, self.y_extremal
                        )
                    self.x_extremal = np.delete(self.x_extremal, idx)
                    self.y_extremal = np.delete(self.y_extremal, idx)
                elif event.button is MouseButton.LEFT:
                    ix, iy, idx = get_closest(ix, self.x, self.y)
                    self.x_extremal = np.append(self.x_extremal, ix)
                    self.y_extremal = np.append(self.y_extremal, iy)
                self.lins.set_data(self.x_extremal, self.y_extremal)
                plt.draw()
                return

    def press(self):
            """Usual function to connect matplotlib.."""
            self.cid = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
                'button_press_event', self.on_clicked
                )

    def release(self):
            """ On release functionality. It's never called  but we will
            need this later on.."""
            self.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid)

    @property
    def selected_points(self):
        """ Returns the selected points."""
        return self.lins.get_data()
```

The easiest way you can try it (even though it doesn't really make sense with random values):

```
x = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
y = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
e = EditPeak(x, y, x[::2], y[::2])
print(e.selected_points)
```

As suggested, a better example is:

```py
x = np.linspace(0,20,100)
y = np.cos(x) + 0.5 * np.random.normal(size=x.shape)
e = EditPeak(x, y, x[::4], y[::4])
print(e.selected_points)
```

I really appreciate every improvement in the code.

Comment: You can make example data more sensible by using something like : `x = np.linspace(0,20,100)`, `y = np.cos(x) + 0.5 * np.random.normal(size=x.shape)` and `e = EditPeak(x, y, x[::15], y[::15])`. As long as there are no answers, it is oke to change the question.